Natural isomorphism between dual spaces
I'm having trouble following an interesting explanation of why the isomorphism between a vector space and its double dual is natural.  The explanation is in an answer to a question posted on physicsforum.

think of it this way: suppose you have V, and V*. given v in V, how can you unambiguously choose an f in V* that goes with v? you can't just use f(v), because there are multiple f in V* wih f(v) all the same. you have to compare how f acts on a basis to distinguish it from all the other linear functionals (and a basis is the smallest set of vectors that will do). in other words, to figure out which linear functional you have, you need n independent "test-values". this is because f collapses n values to 1 value. the reason we DON'T need to do this for V**, is that if we have n^2 values collapsing down to n, that is the same as having n values (a vector in F^n) to start with.

I get the part about how you need $n$ test values ($n$ test vectors) to determine an $f$ in $V^*$, but I don't get the part about $V^{**}$ where $n^2$ values collapse to $n$ values.  Where does the $n^2$ and $n$ come from?

It's impossible to be sure about the intent, but if you think of a functional acting on a single vector as reducing $n$ values to $1$, then you can think of an element of $V^{**}$ applied to a basis of $V^*$ (of size $n$) as reducing $n \times n$ values to $n$ values. This is not a good distinction between $V^*$ and $V^{**}$ since you can just as well think of elements of $V^*$ that way, applied to a basis of $V$.

I think I see what you mean - since each basis vector of $V^$ is a functional that reduces $n$ values to one value, and there are $n$ basis vectors, altogether there are $n \times n$ values reducing to $n$ values.  An element of $V^{**}$ is applied to a basis of $V^$ because to identify the element it's necessary to know how it acts on the basis. Do I have that right?

That is how I interpret it, yes
